# JavaCV face recognition - incompatible types

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I'm trying to compile the http://pcbje.com/2012/12/doing-face-recognition-with-javacv/ code on Android, using the 'quick start' build from https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/README.md#quick-start-for-opencv-and-ffmpeg
I'm getting two errors:

- The method `train(opencv_core.MatVector, opencv_core.Mat)` in the type `opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer` is not applicable for the arguments `(opencv_core.MatVector, int[])`
- The method `predict(opencv_core.Mat)` in the type `opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer` is not applicable for the `arguments (opencv_core.IplImage)`

I've tried converting methods but I keep on reaching dead ends and I don't see how I could've built the project incorrectly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The method train(opencv_core.MatVector, opencv_core.Mat) in the type opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer is not applicable for the arguments (opencv_core.MatVector, int[])

specifically

> not applicable for the arguments (opencv_core.MatVector, int[])

It tells you int that error message that is is expecting a second variable of type opencv_core.Mat and you are passing in an int[].

---

> The method predict(opencv_core.Mat) in the type opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer is not applicable for the arguments (opencv_core.IplImage)

again, you are passing an IplImage (the old type) into a function that requires a Mat.